# Default MVC route if url begins with Admin and contains X parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have an angular application, which i have split into 2, because of functionality.  For here, we will call the apps Default and Admin.

In my ASP.NET MVC Website, i have this route defined, which will catch all URLs and load the Home/Index.cshtml view.

```
// Mvc routes
app.UseMvc(builder =>
{
    // default goes to Home, and angular will deal with client side routing     
    builder.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "home", action = "index" });
});
```

Now if the user goes to a URL that contains the word admin (eg. www.mysite.com/admin or www.mysite.com/admin/something) then i would like to return my Admin/Index.cshtml view.

To accompolish this, i have added my `AdminController` as so

```
[Authorize]
public class AdminController : Controller
{
    [Route("~/Admin/{id?}")]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

But if i try and load a url with more than 2 parameters, such as www.mysite.com/admin/page/12 my Home/Index.cshtml is being returned.

How can i get my Admin view to be returned if the word Admin is after the domain name, no matter how many parameters are in the URL??

Answer (score 1):

Change your code like below:

```
routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback-admin",
        template: "admin/{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index" });

routes.MapRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        template: "{*url}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Route("~/Admin/{id?}")] just can't catch www.mysite.com/admin/page/12, so it moves on to default route. You should either pass your parameters via query string, or add different actions for each parameter combination.

```
[Route("~/Admin/")]
public IActionResult Index(int? id, int page){}
```

So you can use www.mysite.com/admin/?id=1&page=12